# Hibernate with constant table changes

Tags: hibernate, orm

I'm new to Hibernate. Is there a good way to handle **constant changes against table fields or relationships**(especially relationships)?  Reverse-mapping from table into Jave code(Bean) using auto tools such as DB Browser will overwrite all Hibernate config files and .Java files, so we have to manually modify code in Java code and .xml?

In other words, Hibernate is only a tool to generate skeleton code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is an ORM which is designed to help make life easier when using the database within an OO context. See [here](http://hibernate.org/orm/what-is-an-orm/) for an explanation on ORM.

You shouldn't need to constantly change your database layout. If you do, there is no way around the need for changing your configuration files for Hibernate. There are ways to make the process easier though. Perhaps expound on your particular situation for more direct advice?

I know of no tools that can auto-update your configuration and class files intelligently. You would still need to refactor the rest of your code because references to outdated or new class variables would need to be changed!

In general there are various good practices that I would advise;

- Only map the fields that you require. Know that you don't actually need to map every field in a table - or any relationship for that matter.
- Hibernate can handle field name changes easily. This is a small edit in the configuration file or annotation allowing you to use a different class variable to that of the column name.
- Move from using `.hbm.xml` configuration files to specifying the mapping directly in the Java code using [Annotations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/). This will leave you with only one location to make an edit.
- Go back to the drawing board and apply a bit of Software Engineering. Analyse your requirements and data and create a robust design of the database layout before even writing or looking at your code. Create an Entity Relationship Diagram for the design.

Comment: Basically I prefer to database thinking paradigm, but it's very raw and needs to use in OO context.  e.g.,  there are complex relationships in tables, and using raw SQL we can get lots of information. But when it's converted into Hibernate, I don't know what would be like.

Comment: Sounds like you simply need to read up on what an ORM/Hibernate can do in your situation. It's not just mapping.. but can definitely map complex relationships and can be very helpful if you know what you are doing. There is a learning curve once you go beyond simple mappings. If you are using Spring, you'll want to integrate it. One way might be to ignore using the mapping part and use it for the sessionFactory - creating your own custom SQL with a hibernate session - you can then choose to do mapping later..